# How to get the total sum of a column and get total records at the same time

Tags: mysql

I would like to avoid using 2 querys so I am not sure if this is possible. I would like to get the total SUM of a column (which I know how to do) AND also count the total records in that particular table (which I also know how to do)

Problem is that I would like to do both in one query if that is possible.

Here is what I have so far

```
SELECT *, SUM(file_size) as file_size FROM table
```

since I am using SUM only one record comes back which causes my php `$result->num_rows` to return `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(file_size) as file_size FROM table;

Comment: You are the man, that worked and I am ashamed I could not figure that out myself